# how i can use string as a pinname (nodemcu board)

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

```
    String sw1 = serv.arg("sw1"); //provide true or false 
    String w = serv.arg("id");    //provide pin name which i have to operate
    if(sw1 == "true")
      digitalWrite(w , HIGH);
    else
      digitalWrite(w , LOW);
```

in this "w" as string not giving error so I have to convert it in unit8_8 like pin name or pin definition, string w = swa, which define as pin name in setup
how to convert it in pin name

Comment: `w.toInt()` https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/

Comment: its not working value of w = swa when its string and pin is also define as swa

Comment: you will need a look up table to turn the human names into pin numbers. you can use a map().

Comment: i can understand what you want to say, my board is nodeMcu and i am using Arduino IDE to program it